# Can someone explain me how i can set the value that i would like to write inside a textbox/combo box/date timepicker?

Tags: c#, sql, .net

This is the first time when I am working with databases managerial systems, beside what I have studied at the University. So, my question for you guys is this one: how can i write inside an add button function the dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add for every one of the boxex that i mentioned above and also what should i write after equal for combo boxex and date time picker?

```
dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Materiale(mNumar, mDenumire, mUM, mGreutate, mData) VALUES (@mNumar, @mDenumire, @mUM, @mGreutate, @mData", connectionString);
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mNumar", SqlDbType.Int).Value = numarTextBox.Text; ;
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mDenumire", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = denumireTextBox.Text;
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mUM", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = unitateMasuraComboBox.SelectedItem;
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mGreutate", SqlDbType.Int).Value = greutateNumericUpDowm.Value;
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@mData", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

This is the code and based on this code I am asking the question :D

I will thank you from the beggining :D

Comment: I've read it a few times, but it's hard to read. I think you should give more details. Like _"for every one of the boxex that i mentioned above"_ I have no clue what you are refering to. You are adding the sql query parameters. Does it not work?

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: What kind of “textbox/combo box/date time picker”? ASP.NET? MVC? WinForm? WPF?

Comment: @DourHighArch - WinForm

Comment: @TerryTyson - I'm not getting an actual error, am getting an exception, like this "Incorect syntax near "@mData"

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - Sorry for my lack of details, i was refeering at the text box, combo box and datetimepicker that I am using. And yes, it doesn't work, but I'm not getting an error, I'm getting an exception and I think it is based on how I am adding my data, for example: for columns of type varchar i need to use textBox1.Text, but i don't know what i should use for Date and Int.

Answer (score 1):

As your reaction in a comment explains:
*"I'm not getting an actual error, am getting an exception, like this "Incorect syntax near "@mData" "*

An exception is an error. Which mostly leads to the solution.

The incorrect syntax is because you forgot to **close** the *VALUES* **parentheses**.

```
dataAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Materiale(mNumar, mDenumire, mUM, mGreutate, mData) 
    VALUES (@mNumar, @mDenumire, @mUM, @mGreutate, @mData", connectionString);
                                                         ^
```

`@mData", connectionString);` should be `@mData)", connectionString);`